# unactivated tripwires

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an tripwire enderman farm as shown here:
[image]

At initial setup, the tripwires did activate(with the click sound) and I also did check that the tripwires did extend the pistons but after awhile, the tripwires suddenly deactivates and when I test it out, the pistons does not extend.

My tripwire enderman farm is very similar to the one in this video:

Any ideas?

EDIT: Oh, too bad this question is closed. Short follow up: the trip wires will work a lot better if the on the sandstone floor. Maybe because it is a totally even flooring.

EDIT2: Since from the previous edit, I felt guilty for not sticking to my problem initially so I changed half a layer of my design back to tripwires and this is the result:
[image]

It works a lot better with no blocks under the trip wire hooks as Kevin Reid suggested.

EDIT3: Moved all the edits below the question and also.

In my conclusion, from what I can see tripwires works the best when there is either a block under every tripwires and tripwire hooks or no blocks at all under each of the tripwire components.

Comment: Please try to write descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: Since the OP has rejected an answer with the comment *"Thanks for pointing out the possible bug but unfortunately since then I have radically changed my enderman farm design and sadly my new design new problems"*, this question should be closed. I picked "too localised", but "not a real question" probably fits too.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie if OP is the only person who could have this problem is OP it should've been closed from the start, if not then it shouldn't be closed even if OP lost interest.

Comment: @kotekzot As this is a tech-support style question, back-and-forth will be necessary to resolve it. Since now the OP has basically abandoned it we can't get confirmation on what's wrong, nor updates clarifying anything. Without the OP this is just going to sit here and rot. (Perhaps this is the root of the objection to tech-support questions—that they are all, essentially, too localised.)

Comment: @kotekzot This question could perhaps be salvaged by overhauling it to be more general to tripwires rather than about fixing this particular trap design. I'd be concerned that it would no longer be a "practical question" then, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your tripwire hooks at the far end are over solid blocks. [There are known glitches in this case](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-13129). For fully reliable behavior, make sure that the tripwire hooks at both ends are over empty space just as the tripwire itself is.

(I'm not at all sure this is the entire problem, but it can't hurt to fix this.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible bug but unfortunately since then I have radically changed my enderman farm design and sadly my new design new problems..

Comment: @user1602020 If you've radically changed the design, is this question still relevant at all? If not, we should close it.

Comment: Kevin, I have changed the setup to your specifications and it worked better (See my Edits above). Thanks for answering.                          @SevenSidedDie Sorry for not answering , I live in a different timezone  and I was sleeping

Comment: I can double confirm your answer. I was fiddling with my enderman farm just now and accidentally added a block under one of the tripwire hooks. After a random amount of time, the tripwire inactivates(or I should say, the tripwire hooks "retracts") with a "spring" sound. The tripwire activates again immediately when I removed the block under the tripwire hook. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

Your tripwire hooks appear to not be extended. I am guessing that you lost a string at some point.  In fact I think your design may be flawed.  If something is directly below a piece of string it attaches to the floor.   If there is air below the string it floats.  I suspect when the pistons extend the string is going from being attached to the air to being attached to the piston.  Then the piston retracts and the string completely drops.

Comment: Your answer might be correct but I did not mark it as one because from my observations, the strings did not pop out upon the extension of the pistons. Also, visually the strings does not seems to be lowered onto the extended pistons. Nonetheless, thanks for helping me out :)